# PHP & SQL : Throws fatal error when $_Request are filled

Tags: php, mysql, fatal-error

I just started learning, but why is it that when I don't fill the info in the URL it connects to the database, but when I fill it in it gives a fatal error?

Ex. when I type

> http://ehlien.com/php/signup.php?firstname=Mohamed&lastname=Mohamed&username=alpha&email=mohamed.mohd@hotmail.com&password=mohamed

It throws:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Failed to connect to database' in /home/torokage/public_html/php/classes/DB.class.php:22 Stack trace: #0 /home/torokage/public_html/php/signup.php(35): DB->connect() #1 {main} thrown in /home/torokage/public_html/php/classes/DB.class.php on line 22
```

But when I type

http://ehlien.com/php/signup.php

It gives me my error I set up:

```
{"status":"400","message":"Please fill in the missing information..."}
```

I don't have a lot of knowledge on php and mysql, just trying to figure it out on my own and through some tutorials but I can't get this to work to continue...

CODE, signup.php:

```
<?php

require('classes/User.class.php');
require('classes/DB.class.php');
require('classes/Connection.class.php');


$firstname  = null;
$lastname   = null;
$username   = null;
$email      = null;
$password   = null;
$repassword = null;

if (empty($_REQUEST["firstname"])   ||
    empty($_REQUEST["lastname"])        ||
    empty($_REQUEST["username"])        ||
    empty($_REQUEST["email"])       ||
    empty($_REQUEST["password"]))
{
    $returnError["status"] = "400";
    $returnError["message"] = "Please fill in the missing information...";
    echo json_encode($returnError);
    return;
}

$firstname = htmlentities($_REQUEST["firstname"]);
$lastname = htmlentities($_REQUEST["lastname"]);
$username = htmlentities($_REQUEST["username"]);
$email = htmlentities($_REQUEST["email"]);
$password = md5(htmlentities($_REQUEST["password"]));


$DB = new DB(Connection::$db_host, Connection::$db_name, Connection::$db_user, Connection::$db_pass);
$DB->connect();

$checkUsername = $DB->checkIfUsernameExists($username);
if (!empty($checkUsername))
{
    $returnError["status"] = "400";
    $returnError["message"] = "That username has already been taken. Please try again...";
    echo json_encode($returnError);
    return;
}

$checkEmail = $DB->checkIfEmailExists($email);
if (!empty($checkEmail))
{
    $returnError["status"] = "400";
    $returnError["message"] = "That email has already been taken. Please try again...";
    echo json_encode($returnError);
    return;
}

$signUpUser = $DB->signUpUser($firstname, $lastname, $username, $email, $password);
if ($signUpUser)
{
    $userDetails = $DB->getUserDetails($username);
    $user["status"] = "200";
    $user["message"] = "Success! You have now been registered.";
    $user["ID"] = $userDetails["ID"];
    $user["firstname"] = $userDetails["firstname"];
    $user["lastname"] = $userDetails["lastname"];
    $user["username"] = $userDetails["username"];
    $user["email"] = $userDetails["email"];
}
else 
{
    $user["status"] = "400";
    $user["message"] = "Sorry, this account has already been taken. Please try again...";
}

$DB->disconnect();

echo json_encode($user);

?>
```

DB.class.php

```
<?php
class DB {
    protected $db_host = null;
    protected $db_name = null;
    protected $db_user = null;
    protected $db_pass = null;
    protected $db_conn = null;
    protected $db_resu = null;

    // Constructor
    function __construct($db_host, $db_name, $db_user, $db_pass) {
        $this->db_host = $db_host;
        $this->db_name = $db_name;
        $this->db_user = $db_user;
        $this->db_pass = $db_pass;
    }

    // Connect to database
    public function connect() {
        $this->db_conn = new MySQLi($this->db_host, $this->db_name, $this->db_user, $this->db_pass);
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
            throw new Exception("Failed to connect to database");
        $this->db_conn->set_charset("utf8"); 
    }

    // Disconnect from database
    public function disconnect() {
        if ($this->db_conn != null)
            $this->db_conn->close();
    }

    // Check if username exists
    public function checkIfUsernameExists($username) {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT USERNAME FROM USERS WHERE EMAIL = '$username'");
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0){
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    // Check if email exists
    public function checkIfEmailExists($email) {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT EMAIL FROM USERS WHERE EMAIL = '$email'");
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0){
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }


    // Get user informationd
    public function getUserDetails($username) {
        $command = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME = '$username'");
        $value = array();
        $result = $this->db_conn->query($command);

        if ($result != null && (mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1)) {
            $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

            if (!empty($row)) {
                $value = $row;
            }
        }

        return $value;
    }

    // Sign up new user
    public function signUpUser($firstname, $lastname, $username, $email, $password) {
        $command = "INSERT INTO USERS SET FIRSTNAME=?, LASTNAME=?, USERNAME=?, EMAIL=?, PASSWORD=?";
        $sql = $this->db_conn->prepare($command);

        if (!$sql)
            throw new Exception($sql->error);

        $sql->bind_param("sssss", $firstname, $lastname, $username, $email, $password);
        $value = $sql->execute();

        return $value;  
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: You are using `mysqli` and `mysql_`. You also are varying from parameterized queries and non-secure ones. Use all parameterized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you didn't use any value or parameters, it's showing the error set up by you because it couldn't pass the validation step set up by you.

But when you are passing the values or parameters, it passes your validation and tries to connect with the database first as per this code of yours:
`$DB = new DB(Connection::$db_host, Connection::$db_name, Connection::$db_user, Connection::$db_pass);
$DB->connect();`

But it throws an exception: `Failed to connect to database` meaning that your database connection credentials are wrong and thus, can not connect with the database.

You may get more friendly error message by changing inside the `public function connect()` of `DB`class to this:

`// Connect to database
    public function connect() {
        try {
            $this->db_conn = new MySQLi($this->db_host, $this->db_name, $this->db_user, $this->db_pass);
            $this->db_conn->set_charset("utf8");
        } catch (Exception $e ) {
            echo "Failed to connect to database";
            echo "Error: " . $e->message;   // remove when in live...
        }
    }`